# get the selected fill color with openpyxl of a cell using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

With this code I can print the fill-color of cell C23. But when I am using conditional formatting it doesn't return the current color but the color before the conditional formatting.

```
import openpyxl
W = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
p2 = W.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'sheet')
print p2["C24"].fill.start_color.index
print p2["C24"].value
```

Is there a way to get the current fill-color of a conditional and not conditional formatted cell?

Comment: Not without evaluating the relevant condition, which won't be easy.

Comment: W = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx",data_only=True) is working for formulad but not making the difference in my case

Comment: Won't make any difference. openpyxl is a library for the file format, not an Excel replacement.